# CSS/jQuery - responsive design getting close button to stay in right hand corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a popup that stays fixed in the middle of the screen no matter how the user resizes his/her window

here is the js im using to accomplish this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  return $(".wrapper").css({
  position: "fixed",
  left: ($(window).width() - $(".wrapper").outerWidth()) / 2,
  top: ($(window).height() - $(".wrapper").outerHeight()) / 2
 });
});
```

i feel like this works ok......i think my problem is within the css

when the user squishes the window height down my close button goes to the right since the div wrapper that the image is in does not seem to want to reisize with the image.

here is my fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/jBM8Z/1/

so if you squish the height of the window browser down the close button will move away but if you refresh the page the close button snaps back into place.......

I just want the close button to be with his friend the image

Answer (score 1):

You're not adjusting the width of `wrapper` during the resize, so it is being left at its original size. Try pulling it in by setting it to the same width as the image:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function() {
      return $(".wrapper").css({
        position: "fixed",
        left: ($(window).width() - $(".wrapper").outerWidth()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $(".wrapper").outerHeight()) / 2,
        width: $(".wrapper img").width()
      });
    });
  });
```

Note that if you have any padding on `wrapper`, you may need to adjust the width to take account of this.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I recommend checking out the [Debounced Resize](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize) plugin for jQuery, so that your updates only fire when someone is finished resizing the window instead of continuously while they are resizing it.